# Solving a nonlinear, second order d.e. in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equation
$$
s''(x) = \frac{8}{9}s(x) -2s^2(x) + s^3(x),
$$
with boundary conditions $s(-30) = 4/3 $ and $s(30)=0$, in Mathematica by using the following code:

```
sol = NDSolve[{s''[x] == 8/9 s[x] - 2 s[x]^2 + s[x]^3, s[-30] == 4/3, 
s[30] == 0}, s, {x, -30, 30}]
Plot[s[x] /. sol, {x, -30, 30}].
```

However, Mathematica gives me an infinite sequence of errors. Is it just my ignorance concerning the numerical solvability of this kind of nasty differential equations, or is there a way to let Mathematica solve this equation neatly?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a solution for your boundary conditions? Even for a linear case, this is only guaranteed for initial-value problems, where you'd provide values of `s` and its derivative at one and the same point.

Comment: When this happens I'd try to provide initial conditions for the derivative and see how it influences the value at t=30.  I'd also look at the stability of the system.  Try plotting `Plot[8/9 s[x] - 2 s[x]^2 + s[x]^3, {s[x], -1, 2}]` and you'll see that the solution is unstable (and grows without bounds) if you use initial condition 4/3.  Are you sure you didn't want to use another zero of `8/9 s[x] - 2 s[x]^2 + s[x]^3` and use initial condition 2/3?  That would make it stable.

Comment: If you do start at 4/3, I believe these is a solution but this instability (exponential growth) and the range of the variable (30 - (-30) = 60) makes it very difficult to find a solution.  Instead, realize that `x` doesn't appear anywhere in the equation, so first it's invariant to translation along `x`.  The solution can also be rescaled by a transformation `x -> a*x`.  I'd try to use the range x=0..1 and rescale the solution for a range of -30..30.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any differential operator includes boundary conditions in its definition. Therefore, there is no translational invariance, since it is obviously broken by the boundary conditions (finite region).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin You can translate the boundaries too---what I meant was that it doesn't matter if you solve on -30..30 (boundary conditions on -30 and 30) or on 0..60 (boundary conditions on 0 and 60).  What matters is that the interval length is 60.  It turns out that because of the exponential increase in this system, a long interval is really a problem.  If you formulate the problem using initial conditions both for the function and its derivative, there'll be an extreme sensitivity to the value of the derivative.  That's why things go wrong (NDSolve uses the shooting method I think)

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, I see what you meant. I agree with this.

Comment: @Funzies what was the error your received with NDSolve? I am trying to solve this with a stiff solver such as LSODA and I've been receiving an `NDSolve::berr` error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is my take on it. Your equation appears to be a stiff one, given your initial condition in `s`.

#### General

First observation is that you can integrate your equation exactly. To do this, make a substitution:

$\phi(s) = s'(t)$

Then, you have

$s''(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\phi(s) = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{s}} \frac{\partial s}{\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial{s}} \phi = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial{s}}\phi(s)^2$

Therefore, the new equation is

$\frac{\partial}{\partial{s}}\phi(s)^2 = 2(8/9 s - 2 s^2 + s^3)$

which means that

$\phi(s) = \pm \sqrt{const + \frac{1}{18} (4-3 s)^2 s^2}$,

and, recalling what `phi[s]` is, we have (picking the negative branch of the square root):

$dt = -\frac{ds}{\sqrt{const + \frac{1}{18} (4-3 s)^2 s^2}}$

Integrating this, we get

$rhs(s,c) = - \int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{const + \frac{1}{18} (4-3 s)^2 s^2}}$

and then

$t(s) = -30 + rhs(s,c) - rhs(4/3,c)$

where the unknown coefficient `c` should be found from an equation

$t(0) == 30$.

#### Mathematica

We define

```
ClearAll[t, rhs, s, c];
rhs[s_, c_] = -Integrate[1/Sqrt[c + 1/18 (4 - 3 s)^2 s^2], s];
t[s_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ] = -30 + rhs[s, c] - rhs[4/3, c];
```

Now, we have to solve

```
t[0, c] == 30
```

Which we do like so:

```
const = 
  Block[{c}, 
    Re[c /. FindRoot[t[0, c] == 30, {c, 1/100},
    PrecisionGoal -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxIterations -> 400]]
  ]

(* 1.7115086059709459320105665968527588754036742895311*10^-24 *)
```

This is a very small number, so we needed to use extended precision.

Finally, we can plot `t` as a function of `s`:

```
Plot[
  t[s, const], {s, 0, 4/3}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005]
]
```

[image]

This shows why `NDSolve` had difficulties: it is hard to invert this function, as it is very stiff at both edges. This means that the system spends most time in either of the end-points, and the transition is fairly quick.

Defining

```
ClearAll[s];
s[tt_?NumericQ] := 
  Chop@Block[{s}, 
     s /. FindRoot[
            t[s, const] == tt, {s, 1},
            PrecisionGoal -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
  ]
```

we finally get:

```
Plot[
  s[tt], {tt, -30, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005]
]
```

[image]

which is presumably what you are after.

Note that it may be possible to make `NDSolve` solve this one all right, by playing with options, particularly for stiff systems.

#### A solution on infinite interval

The "physical meaning" of the constant `const` is to take into account boundary effects, very small deviations of the finite but large interval from an infinite interval. If the interval is infinite, then this constant is zero, as is easy to show. In this case, there is a simple analytical solution:

```
tInf[s_] := 3/(2 Sqrt[2]) Log[s/(4 - 3 s)]
```

which is very easy to invert:

```
sInf[t_] = 4/3 - 4/(3 + 9 E^((2 Sqrt[2] t)/3))
```

It is now easy to check that this one satisfies the original equation:

```
FullSimplify[D[sInf[t], {t, 2}] - (8/9 sInf[t] - 2 sInf[t]^2 + sInf[t]^3)]

(* 0 *)
```

Comment: This is a really great answer! Thank you very much Leonid!

Comment: @Funzies You are welcome :). It remains to check that the numerical solution is correct, by substituting into the equation, but that may require extra precision.

Comment: @Funzies Actually, it seems I've made a mistake. Will correct shortly.

Comment: @Funzies I've made some mistake in my calculations, corrected now. It only affected the formulas and constants, the new plots are visually indistinguishable from the old ones. But of course, you should use the new formulas. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Funzies I have added a section on exact solution on infinite interval. It can serve as a starting point of some better approach, something like a perturbation theory in the "proximity of the finite large interval to infinite interval", or, smallness of the coefficient `const`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin NDSolve stiffness, story of my life! I found that using `Method->"LSODA"`. I let the "MaxDifferenceOrder" "float". Given your hightened understanding of this problem, do you have any comment on my positive experience with "LSODA"?

Comment: @drN Sorry, but not really. This is not actually my field, I just toy with this every now and then (very rarely, in fact). I am mostly a programmer now. Most of the things I was doing in the past had explicit analytical representations. The numerical problems I was dealing with did not include stiff DEs, so I can only use some very general common sense here, but I don't possess any detailed knowledge of this area. Consider this a drive-by post :)